# Plot a number of a chosen size

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to have a function `plotnumber[number_, size_]` that produces a number of chosen size.

My current solution is to use an empty plot.

```
plotnumber[n_, size_, ImSize_] := 
  Plot[, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotLabel -> Style[n, size], ImageSize -> ImSize];
```

but this produces an ugly result because the label of a plot always stays on top and I don't have centered picture.

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe `plotnumber[n_, size_, ImSize_] := 
 Graphics[Text[Style[n, size]], ImageSize -> ImSize]`?

Comment: plotn[n_,siz]:=Style[ToString[n], FontSize ->siz]

Comment: @kglr that rocks, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variant with some styling embellishments:

```
ClearAll[plotnumber]
plotnumber[o : OptionsPattern[]][n : (_Integer | _String | _Symbol), size_, ImSize_] := 
 Graphics[Text[Style[n /. x:(_Integer|_Symbol) :> ToString[x], ## & @@ size]], 
  ImageSize -> ImSize, o]
```

Examples:

```
options = Sequence[Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> False, ImagePadding -> 1];
```

The first argument can be `Integer`, `String` or `Symbol`:

```
plotnumber[options][#, {128, Red , FontFamily -> "SegoeScript"}, 200] & /@ 
 {3, "3", "A", A} // Row
```

[image]

Font size in printer units:

```
plotnumber[options][3, {#, Red , FontFamily -> "SegoeScript"}, 200] & /@
 {16, 32, 64, 128} // Row
```

[image]

Scaled font sizes:

```
plotnumber[options][3, {FonrtSize -> #, Red , FontFamily -> "SegoeScript"}, 200] & /@
 (Scaled /@ {.1, .3, .7, 1.}) // Row
```

[image]

Fixed font size versus varying image sizes:

```
plotnumber[options][3, {128, Red , FontFamily -> "SegoeScript"}, #] & /@ 
 {80, 100, 200, 250} // Row
```

[image]

Scaled font size versus varying image sizes:

```
plotnumber[options][3, {FontSize -> Scaled[1], Red , FontFamily ->"SegoeScript"}, #] & /@
 {80, 100, 200, 250} // Row
```

[image]